# Need advice on fixing MySQL database design & table structure

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am planning to create a web application that using php-mysql, I created database to provide to store the form results. I create each column for each input fields in the database, It's working fine except that people tell that I'm doing it wrong because the database design that I created is "too static, bulky".

I created these columns: date, name, address, phone, bla bla, service1, service_price1, service2, service_price2, service3, service_price3, service4, service_price4, service5, service_price5, part1, part_price1, part2, part_price2, part3, part_price3.

I think my database columns is too bulky and static especially in the service and part. I'm looking for a better way to design my database and making it viewable in query results. Any advice for me? Thanks in advance

Here is my form sample:
[image]

Here is my database structure:
[image]

Comment: Here's a quick recommendation: instead of having all of those service price columns, and services in all these columns, why not just store a serialized variable in one column that contains this informatoin?

Comment: No, how about have a services table and a parts table. Look up database normalization and joins in your queries. This is not a question looking for a specific answer though, so expect it to be closed shortly!

Comment: What @miken32 said, you will definitly want to split those into new tables. One advantage you will get is that you easily can add a "add another service/part" button and have a variable amount of these.

Comment: @JimL Thanks for the reply, can I make a subtotal/total calculation from each entries in that new table? can i post to two different table in a single submit form?

Comment: Yes. In fact it's very common to store form data to a selection of tables instead of only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split this into multiple tables, one for customers, one for products (services), one for orderItems, and one for orders.

The orderItem table can hold reference to the customer and the list of products in this order, for example:

```
orderItemId_a : orderId_1 : customerId_a : productId_01
orderItemId_b : orderId_1 : customerId_a : productId_03
```

etc.